# How to Create Google Cloud Storage Signed Urls on App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I couldn't find a simple example on how to implement Google Cloud Storage Signed Urls on Google App Engine with Python. Please write a step by step guide. :)

Answer (score 7):

I created this repo: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-signed-url

Using GAE Pyrthon `app_identity.get_service_account_name()` and `app_identity.sign_blob()` makes creating signed url's very easy, without using a PEM key. The app shows how to download a GCS file.

But if you use the SDK to test the app, you have to use:

1. --appidentity_email_address
2. --appidentity_private_key_path

because creating a signed url is not part of the GCS client.

Answer (score 6):

The other solutions work but there is a simpler way using [generate_signed_url](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.generate_signed_url). This method does the same thing as @voscausa's answer but is less tedious and has custom exceptions and support for other environments.

```
def sign_url(obj, expires_after_seconds=60):

    client = storage.Client()
    default_bucket = '%s.appspot.com' % app_identity.get_application_id()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(default_bucket)
    blob = storage.Blob(obj, bucket)

    expiration_time = int(time.time() + expires_after_seconds)

    url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration_time)

    return url
```

What vascausa said regarding local development server testing

> But if you use the SDK to test the app, you have to use:
>
> --appidentity_email_address
>
> --appidentity_private_key_path
>
> because creating a signed url is not part of the GCS client.

still holds.

Comment: I tried this approach, but I'm getting an error:
`AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. see https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/auth.html?highlight=authentication#setting-up-a-service-account for more details.`
I was under the impression that this would work by default since the service runs using the default service acount. What am I missing?

Comment: Testing locally works fine when setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the json keyfile matching the service account

Comment: @ajn I'm getting the same issue, did you find a work around?

Comment: @AriVictor The work around in our case was that we implemented it in java instead. Don't want the hassle of providing explicit serve account credentials, but also didn't want to use python 2.7.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how we made it work:

**Step 1: Get p12 file/certificate**

Download p12 file from https://console.developers.google.com/  
“APIs & auth / Credentials” tab.

**Step 2: Convert p12 file to DER format**

Find a Linux computer open and connect using Terminal
Command:
  openssl pkcs12 -in  -nodes -nocerts > 
      # The current Google password for the p12 file is `notasecret`

Command:
   openssl rsa -in  -inform PEM -out  -outform DER

**Step 3: Convert DER file to base64 encoded string**

Python console:

```
private_key = open(‘<filename.der>’, 'rb').read()
print private_key.encode('base64')
```

Copy and paste into App engine script.

**Step 4: Enable PyCrypto in AppEngine**

app.yaml must have a line to enable PyCrypto:

```
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
```

**Step 5: Python code to create Signed URL**

```
import Crypto.Hash.SHA256 as SHA256
import Crypto.PublicKey.RSA as RSA
import Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5 as PKCS1_v1_5

der_key = “””<copy-paste-the-base64-converted-key>”””.decode('base64')

bucket = <your cloud storage bucket name (default is same as app id)>
filename = <path + filename>

valid_seconds = 5
expiration = int(time.time() + valid_seconds)

signature_string = 'GET\n\n\n%s\n' % expiration
signature_string += bucket + filename



# Sign the string with the RSA key.
signature = ''
try:
  start_key_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
  rsa_key = RSA.importKey(der_key, passphrase='notasecret')
  #objects['rsa_key'] = rsa_key.exportKey('PEM').encode('base64')
  signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsa_key)
  signature_hash = SHA256.new(signature_string)
  signature_bytes = signer.sign(signature_hash)
  signature = signature_bytes.encode('base64')

  objects['sig'] = signature
except:
  objects['PEM_error'] = traceback.format_exc()

try:
  # Storage
  STORAGE_CLIENT_EMAIL = <Client Email from Credentials console: Service Account Email Address>
  STORAGE_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://storage.googleapis.com'

  # Set the query parameters.
  query_params = {'GoogleAccessId': STORAGE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
                'Expires': str(expiration),
                'Signature': signature}


  # This is the signed URL:
  download_href = STORAGE_API_ENDPOINT + bucket + filename + '?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params)

except:
  pass
```

**Sources**

[How to get the p12 file.](http://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication)

[Signing instructions.](http://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs)

[Inspiration for how to sign the url.](http://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python)